# JQuery Mobile ASP.NET Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop'

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile webpage in ASP.NET MVC 3, razor views but they appear blank.
Google chrome Developer tool gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop'. Tried some google solutions (most said to make sure I first include jquery then JQM) but nothing solved it.

Error:

> jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has
>   no method 'prop'
>       d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWithjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
>       d.extend.readyjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
>       c.addEventListener.A

Code:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Do you have 2 `</head>` closing tags in your real code, or is this a copy and paste error?

Comment: It was a real error but isn't the problem, took it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed the JQuery version which came with the creation of my project is a bit outdated. Using jquery v1.7 now and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there may have been a bug in 1.5.1.

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/358